# writing TraversalDescription to exclude edges with certain properties

Tags: neo4j

I would like to write a TraversallDescription that I can use with a Walker. My ultimate goal to to pass the Walker to GraphvizWriter so I can get the results of the traversal in .dot format.

In my graph I have only one type of node and only one type of relationship. Each relationship has a property named "inCommon" which has numerical value. I only want nodes which have inCommon >= 15 on the relation between them.

Here is what my traversalDescription looks like:

```
traversalDescription = graphDb.traversalDescription();
traversalDescription = traversalDescription.breadthFirst();
traversalDescription = traversalDescription.evaluator(pathEvaluator);
traversalDescription = traversalDescription.relationships(type, Direction.BOTH);
```

pathEvaluator is an instance of a class I wrote to attempt to only return the edges I want.

```
public class ReferentEvaluator implements PathEvaluator {
    @Override 
    public Evaluation evaluate(final Path path) {
        if(path!=null){
            Iterator iter=path.relationships().iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Relationship r=(Relationship)iter.next();
                if(r!=null){
                    Integer inCommon=(Integer)r.getProperty(r.getPropertyKeys().iterator().next());
                    if(inCommon.intValue() < 15){
                        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                }
            }
            return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
        }
    return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

What I am seeing is that this doesn't work. Relations with inCommon < 15 are being included. This approach doesn't seem to work at all, actually. Am I going about this completely the wrong way? Or is what am I doing here getting close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to understand regarding the traversal framework is that it operates on paths. The evaluator always gets the whole path from your starting node to the current position in the graph. So the second important thing to realize is that the distinguishing state change between the paths is their end node. Your evaluator will with each call to `evaluate()` get a path ending in a new node (sometimes depending on other restrictions on your traversal, see uniqueness etc.).

What's important here is that your evaluator always iterates through *all* edges of the current path and *as soon* as it discovers an edge that has `inCommon < 15` it will stop *although* later in the path there still can be nodes you would be interested in.

As a note however, I do not see how the result would *include* unwanted nodes; in my tests the evaluator would correctly reject unwanted nodes however miss wanted nodes.

Please see this code that in my mind does what you desire. It is derived from the Neo4j traversal documentation (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_pathexpander_relationshipexpander) to make understanding easier. I just added 'Nici' to have more room for experiments and a showcase that the algorithm is working correctly:

[image: Who-knows-who]

Here's the code:

```
public class Neo4jTest {

public static enum EdgeTypes implements RelationshipType {
    KNOWS
}

private static final String PROP_COMMON = "inCommon";
private static final String PROP_NAME = "name";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("src/main/resources/graph.db");
    try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
        Node lars = graphDb.createNode();
        Node sara = graphDb.createNode();
        Node ed = graphDb.createNode();
        Node lisa = graphDb.createNode();
        Node peter = graphDb.createNode();
        Node dirk = graphDb.createNode();
        Node joe = graphDb.createNode();
        Node nici = graphDb.createNode();

        lars.setProperty(PROP_NAME, "Lars");
        sara.setProperty(PROP_NAME, "Sara");
        ed.setProperty(PROP_NAME, "Ed");
        lisa.setProperty(PROP_NAME, "Lisa");
        peter.setProperty(PROP_NAME, "Peter");
        dirk.setProperty(PROP_NAME, "Dirk");
        joe.setProperty(PROP_NAME, "Joe");
        nici.setProperty(PROP_NAME, "Nici");

        joe.createRelationshipTo(sara, EdgeTypes.KNOWS).setProperty(PROP_COMMON, 20);
        lisa.createRelationshipTo(joe, EdgeTypes.KNOWS).setProperty(PROP_COMMON, 7);
        peter.createRelationshipTo(sara, EdgeTypes.KNOWS).setProperty(PROP_COMMON, 14);
        dirk.createRelationshipTo(peter, EdgeTypes.KNOWS).setProperty(PROP_COMMON, 19);
        lars.createRelationshipTo(dirk, EdgeTypes.KNOWS).setProperty(PROP_COMMON, 8);
        ed.createRelationshipTo(lars, EdgeTypes.KNOWS).setProperty(PROP_COMMON, 12);
        lisa.createRelationshipTo(lars, EdgeTypes.KNOWS).setProperty(PROP_COMMON, 3);
        nici.createRelationshipTo(lars, EdgeTypes.KNOWS).setProperty(PROP_COMMON, 23);

        ReferentEvaluator pathEvaluator = new ReferentEvaluator();
        EdgeTypes type = EdgeTypes.KNOWS;
        TraversalDescription traversalDescription = graphDb.traversalDescription();
        traversalDescription = traversalDescription.breadthFirst();
        traversalDescription = traversalDescription.evaluator(pathEvaluator);
        traversalDescription = traversalDescription.relationships(type, Direction.BOTH);

        String output = "";
        String names = "";
        for (Path position : traversalDescription.traverse(joe)) {
            output += position + "\n";

        }
        System.out.println("Evaluator traversal:");
        System.out.println(output);
        System.out.println("Nodes with 'inCommon' edges >= 15:");
        for (Node node : traversalDescription.traverse(joe).nodes()) {
            names += node.getProperty("name") + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(names);
        System.out.println("\n");

    }
    graphDb.shutdown();
}

private static class ReferentEvaluator implements Evaluator {
    @Override
    public Evaluation evaluate(final Path path) {
        // just check for each end node if it fits to the restriction
        Node endNode = path.endNode();
        Iterable<Relationship> relationships = endNode.getRelationships(EdgeTypes.KNOWS);
        for (Relationship rel : relationships) {
            if (rel.hasProperty(PROP_COMMON) && ((int) rel.getProperty(PROP_COMMON) > 15))
                return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
        }
        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;

    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
    Evaluator traversal:
(6)
(6)--[KNOWS,0]-->(1)
(6)--[KNOWS,0]-->(1)<--[KNOWS,2]--(4)
(6)<--[KNOWS,1]--(3)--[KNOWS,6]-->(0)
(6)--[KNOWS,0]-->(1)<--[KNOWS,2]--(4)<--[KNOWS,3]--(5)
(6)<--[KNOWS,1]--(3)--[KNOWS,6]-->(0)<--[KNOWS,7]--(7)

Nodes with 'inCommon' edges >= 15:
Joe
Sara
Peter
Lars
Dirk
Nici
```

You can see that the included paths end in nodes with at least one edge with inCommon >= 15 which is what you wanted, if I understood you correctly. Iterating through the nodes gives us exactly those people who are connected with a green edge in my example graph.

Comment: Suppose there were no edge between Lisa and Lars and also no edge between Peter and Sara. In order to traverse all nodes you'd need the root nodes of Ed and Lisa, right? That is close to the situation that I have: there are many seperate subgraphs. My plan is to run a Cypher query for the root node IDs and then run the traversal, starting at each root node. Does that make sense? The Cypher query I am going to run is `MATCH (n) WHERE NOT (()-[:inCommon]->(n)) RETURN n` where inCommon is the type of the Edge, will that return the root nodes as I want?

Comment: The problem is that in a general graph, you do not necessarily have such a thing as a particular "root" since this is an expression used for the special type of tree graphs. Perhaps you could it that way all the same. Let me ask you something else: Wouldn't it be sufficient for your use case just to iterate through all nodes and return those connected with "green edges" (as depicted in my example picture)? You could do so by using GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb).getAllNodes(); and then for each node check the edges. Without traversals. Wouldn't this be enough?

Comment: Well, ultimately I want the traverser to be passed to the Walker.crosscut() method for use with GraphViz writer. I wonder though...Walker.crosscut()'s first argument is a java.lang.Iterable so maybe I could go through all Nodes with getAllNodes() and stuff the nodes that match the criteria into some Collection that implements Iterable and pass that to Walker.crosscut()?

Comment: I absolutely think so. You would just iterate over all nodes, identify those you want to have and put them into an ArrayList (which is in iterable). Should work! However, I don't know the Walker framework particularly well, I don't know if there could be issues.

Comment: That is what I did, iterated over and filtered nodes and put them in an ArrayList. So far it seems to have worked OK!

Answer (score 3):

I thinks its better to implement the relationship filter in the `PathExpander` than in the `Evaluator`. Reason for that is that you can earlier decide which paths to skip and you don't need to load nodes and filter out later.

Instead of `relationships()` you supply a custom `PathExpander`. The `PathExpander` filters all relationship of the given type with a predicate. The predicate checks if `inCommon` is < 15.

Since we do all the dirty work in the expander we can savely use an evaluator that replies with `INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE` - `Evaluators.all()` does this.

Here's my untested code snippet:

```
import org.neo4j.helpers.Predicate;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.Iterables;
import ...

public void traversalSample() {

    TraversalDescription td = graphDatabaseService
            .traversalDescription()
            .expand(new RelationshipPropertyFilterExpander(
                    DynamicRelationshipType.withName("KNOWS"), Direction.BOTH, 
                    "inCommon", 15)
            )
            .evaluator(Evaluators.all());
    td.traverse(.....);
}

class RelationshipPropertyFilterExpander implements PathExpander<Object> {
    public RelationshipType type;
    public Direction direction;
    public String propName;
    int threshold;

    public RelationshipPropertyFilterExpander(RelationshipType type, Direction direction, 
                                              String propName, int threshold) {
        this.type = type;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.propName = propName;
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Relationship> expand(Path path, BranchState<Object> state) {
        Node endNode = path.endNode();
        Predicate<? super Relationship> predicate = new Predicate<Relationship>() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(Relationship relationship) {
                // if relationship property is not set, we assume 0
                return Integer.parseInt(relationship.getProperty(propName, "0").toString()) < threshold;
            }
        };
        return Iterables.filter(predicate, endNode.getRelationships(type, direction));
    }

    @Override
    public PathExpander<Object> reverse() {
        // gets never called in a unidirectional traversal
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```